# Sequelize query all associated items by another multiple associated items

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

my models looks like this:

user belongs to many categories

post belongs to many categories

through a joint tables of UserCategories and PostCategories

How do I select all posts which has the same categories as user ( for all categories which user is related ).

Answer (score 0):

Get all categories for user.

```
const userCategory =  await UserCategory.findAll({
    where: {
        userId: 1,
    },
    raw: true,
});
```

Get all posts for user categories.

```
const posts = await PostCategory.findAll({
    include: [
        {
            model: Post,
            required: true,
        },
        {
            model: Category,
            required: true,
            include: {
                model: UserCategory,
                required: true,
                include: {
                    model: User,
                    required: true,
                    where: {
                        id: userCategory.map(item => item.categoryId),
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    ],
});
```